# Reading a property on a main thread that is set on a background thread

Tags: multithreading, objective-c

I am currently handling some setup of an object on a background thread (I am using a concurrent queue within the following `initWithDocumentFileURL` method):

```
+ (TWReaderDocument *)initWithDocumentFileURL:(NSURL *)url withLoadingCompletionBlock:(loadingCompletionBlock)completionBlock{

 __block NSError *error;
TWReaderDocument * twDoc = [[TWReaderDocument alloc] init];
twDoc.status = ReaderDocCreated;
twDoc.doc = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:[url path] withURL:url withLoadingCompletionBLock:^(NSError *_error) {

    if (_error)
    {
        _error = error;
        twDoc.status = ReaderDocReady;
    }
    else twDoc.status = ReaderDocFailed;

}];

//completionBlock(error);

return twDoc;
}
```

**Header**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) TWReaderDocumentStatus status;
```

**Implementation**

```
- (TWReaderDocumentStatus) status {

    __block TWReaderDocumentStatus readStatus;

    dispatch_sync([ReaderDocument concurrentLoadingQueue], ^{
        readStatus = _status;
    });

    return readStatus;

}
```

If I would like to access the status property on the main thread do I need to take any precaution or there is nothing to take care of as I am just reading the property on the main thread?

Comment: Unrelated, but what is the intent of the line of code that says `_error = error`? I could imagine `error = _error` if you were trying to save the `NSError` passed to your block (but then again, the idea of updating a `__block` variable from an asynchronous method doesn't make a lot of sense).

Answer (score 3):

If all you're trying to synchronize is `TWReaderDocumentStatus`, and if that's a simple data type (e.g. an integer or float, not an object), you can just define it as `atomic`, and it can be safely read and updated from multiple threads, with no custom getter required. This is one of the very few situations where `atomic` can be useful for synchronization (and it's remarkably efficient).

By the way, if your property has a public interface that is `readonly`, make sure the private class extension redefines it as `readwrite` so the setter is synthesized for you. And make sure that you only set it using the setter (not bypassing it and using the instance variable directly).